# How to automatically increment text value on sequential inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this unordered list which contains some inputs, what I want to do is to type a value on the first input, like "1", then all the other inputs, in order, gets 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this, parse the first value then increment the rest based on their index:

```
$("ol input:first").keyup(function() {
  var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  $("ol input:gt(0)").val(isNaN(val) ? '' : function(i) { return val + i + 1; });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/dhYYR/1/).  The `if`/`else` conditional is  checking if the value's legit, e.g. if you hit backspace and it's empty you won't get `NaN` in every following input, inside we'll blank out the value so it's handled gracefully.

Comment: Love your solution, Nick. still I need to type a value on any given input and all the others ahead gets the value increment.. Like, I type 1 on the 1st, then all the others get 2,3,4,5.  But if I go and change 4 to 10, the 5 go to 11, and the others remain untouched

Answer (score 1):

You could use the each function of jQuery. Something similar to the following:

```
var counter=Number($("input[selector for your first textbox]").val());
$("input[selector for inputs in your list]").each(function()
{
     this.val(++counter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the following markup, you can use jQuery to set the values:

```
<ul>
    <li><input id="start" type="text" /></li>
    <li><input class="auto" type="text" /></li>
    <li><input class="auto" type="text" /></li>
    <li><input class="auto" type="text" /></li>
    <li><input class="auto" type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#start").change(function() {

        // Get the value entered
        var value = new Number($(this).val());

        // Increment the other fields
        $(".auto").each(function() {
            value++;
            $(this).val(value);
        });

    });

});
```

See the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qLpgK/). Note, there's no validation on this, but it'll give you another idea of how to accomplish what you're after.